# Feynman Kac: Perpetual Bond

Tags: feynman-kac

I would like to derive a PDE for a perpetual bond.

Suppose we have a bond that will pay a coupon $C$ until there is a default event that occurs. Take the time of default as $\tau$ and consider the doubly-stochastic process:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d} r_t &= a(m-r_t) \mathrm{d}t +\sigma \sqrt{r_t} \mathrm{d}W_t \\
\mathrm{d} \lambda_t &= \theta(\nu-\lambda_t) \mathrm{d}t +\gamma \sqrt{\lambda_t} \mathrm{d}\hat{W}_t
\end{align*}
$$

Where $r_t$, $\lambda_t$ are the rate and the default intensity respectively. The two Brownian Motions are assumed to be independent, and all other parameters are positive constants. The price of this bond is
$$
\begin{align*}
P &= \mathbb{E} \Big[\int_0^\tau C e^{r_t t}\mathrm{d}t + Ze^{r_\tau \tau}\Big]  \\
\end{align*}
$$

For some $Z \in [0,1]$. I have in my notes that the price satisfies the following PDE
$$
\begin{align*}
a(m-x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \theta(\nu-\lambda_t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\gamma^2y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} - xu + y(Z-u) = 0
\end{align*}
$$

I am not sure where the last two terms came from. I understand that to derive these PDEs, you appeal to the martingale property to "enforce no drift". That said, the solution (understandably) has no time-dependence, so without the discount factor (as with option pricing) I fail to see where the last two terms come from.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Feel free to add/remove/edit tags.

Edit: There was a mistake in the lecture notes.

Edit 2: After closing inspection, I am not satisfied that the explanation that I have been given is correct. I believe the pricing function I have presented above is wrong.

Guidance is much appreciated!